# (C++) Two classes with some common function. Cleanest way to code

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I have two classes that has some common functions and some different functions.

Let's say

```
class Red{
    public:
        void funcA();
        void funcC();
}

class Blue{
    public:
        void funcB();
        void funcC();
}
```

**Note** My actual code contains more functions (both common function and non-common one)

and I need to make a class for an interface that

1. initialize one of the two classes above.
2. contains the function to run each function in the class above if it is available for that class

Here is the example

**interface.cpp**

```
Red *red_object = nullptr;
Blue *blue_object = nullptr;

void init(int mode){
    if (mode == 0) red_object = new Red();
    else blue_object = new Blue();
}

void run_func_a(){
    if (mode == 0) red_object->funcA();
}

void run_func_b(){
    if (mode == 1) blue_object->funcB();
}

void run_func_c(){
    if (mode == 0) {
        red_object->funcC();
    }
    else {
        blue_object->funcC();
    } 
}
```

The problem is, I think it is very clunky (e.g., `run_func_c()`) when I have to write it for every function so I want to somehow generalize it, like using *inheritance*. However, I cannot use it since there is some function that does not exist in both classes. I could fill in an empty function to the one that does not have it but it is not good in the long term.

Is there a better way to construct the interface file in a more precise and cleaner way?

Edit:

I would like to clarify what I imagine in case of inheritance as @AdrianMole mentioned.

I will have a base class `Colour`.

```
class Colour{
    void funcC();
}

class Red: public Colour{
    void funcA();
}
```

But when I want to write the function in **interface.cpp**,

```
Colour colour_object = nullptr;
void init(int mode){
    if(mode ==0) colour_object = new Red();
    else(mode == 0) colour_object = new Blue();
}

void run_func_a(){
    colour_object->funcA(); // This will have error
}

void run_func_c(){
    colour_object->funcC(); // This is okay and looks clean.
}
```

`colour_object->funcA()` will raise an error since it doesn't exist on the base class.

I can just add funcA() in base class, but imagine if I have like 10 common functions, 10 functions unique to `Red` and 10 functions unique to `Blue`. I think that will be a lot of function in base class. (Although if it is the best approach, I might set on this approach)

Comment: Define a **base class** (let's call it `Colour`, for argument's sake) with the common functions in and derive `Red` and `Blue` from that.

Comment: what is "clean" depends on what those classes really are (are they supposed to be colors?) and what `funcX` are doing.

Comment: I do not see the point of not being able to use inheritance because you want more functions, maybe I am not understanding correctly. You can define some methods in the base class and then add your own to the daughter, it is not true that every function in the daughter class must have its own counterpart in the mother.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I cannot tell you exactly but let's assume that I have a `videoPlayer` class and `audioPlayer` class. Both has `play` and `stop` function but maybe I want `audioPlayer` to have `mute` function where `videoPlayer` don't need since it contains no sound in this case.

Comment: @chiappar It is because my actual code has so many functions so I want to make the code clean and easy to read. (Imagine having the `if(mode ==0)` in twenty places). 

Also, I am looking in the long term where if one of my classes has one additional function, I have to go and add it to the mother class. I guess it is doable but I am looking for an idea if there is a better approach.

Comment: Have you considered you need to split your classes up futher? Rule of thumb, a source file should be at max 500 lines, and should aim to have max 7 members (harder to do)

Comment: @Justin It is one of my considerations if there is nothing else better than this.

Comment: Having lots of functions limits how "clean" or "easy to read" your code can be, regardless of how those functions are distributed between base or derived classes - moving common functions into a common base will only get you so far. You may also need to redesign to provide the same overall functionality using a *reduced*  number of functions.  Also, a member function of a derived class (say, a member of `Red` but not of `Colour`) can't be called from code that only has visibility of a `Colour`, unless you can *safely* assume (or ensure) the `Colour` it acts on is *actually* a `Red`.

Comment: `void run_func_a(){ if (mode == 0) red_object->funcA();}` What should happen when mode is not 0? Is this an error? If not, why not?

Comment: To your example of audio/video players, one way could be to write a generic "Player" class that can play and stop, but a more specific one for audio that can also mute. Player should only implement what makes sense for all Players. Conversely, you might decide to have just one Player class with all controls, but whose volume controls simply have no effect if the current file has no audio stream. And yes, in your example you obviously can't call funcA, but even your compiler can see that!

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I seems to write have some mistake in the code. But the idea is that it will do nothing or raise an error because it try to call function that does not exist. (`blue_object` and `funcA` in this case)

Comment: So you have a design that allows the user "call a function that does not exist" (whatever that means). That is, you have types that are lying to your user. Perhaps a redesign is in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **virtual** keyword to archive this.

Example:

```
class Color
{
public:
        void funcColor()
        {
            cout<<"Color::funcColor()\n";
        }
  virtual void funcC()
        {
            cout<<"Color::funcC()\n";
        }
};

class Red : public Color{
    public:
        void funcA()
        {
            cout<<"Red::funcA()\n";
        }
         void funcC()
        {
            cout<<"Red::funcC()\n";
        }
};

class Blue : public Color{
    public:
        void funcB()
        {
             cout<<"Blue::funcB()\n";
        }
         void funcC()
        {
             cout<<"Blue::funcC()\n";
        }
};

int main()
{
    Color *color;
    Blue blue;
    Red red;

    color=&blue;
    color->funcC();
    color=&red;
    color->funcC();

    return 0;
}
```